# Trying to install rofi

Tags: software-installation

I'm running into issues trying to install rofi. https://davedavenport.github.io/rofi/

Using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install rofi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rofi : Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0 (>= 0.5.0) but 0.4.3-2~14.04~ricotz1 is to be installed
        Depends: libxkbcommon0 (>= 0.5.0) but 0.4.3-2~14.04~ricotz1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
How can I fix this?

ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
atlassian-hipchat4.list          numix-ppa-trusty.list.save
atlassian-hipchat4.list.save     patches.list
chrome-remote-desktop.list       patches.list.save
chrome-remote-desktop.list.save  ricotz-testing-trusty.list
elementary.list                  tomato-team-tomato-stable-trusty.list
elementary.list.save             tomato-team-tomato-stable-trusty.list.save
google-chrome.list               versable-elementary-update-trusty.list
google-chrome.list.save          versable-elementary-update-trusty.list.save

cat /etc/apt/source.list
cat: /etc/apt/source.list: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like you might have a PPA which is providing conflicting packages. Can you post the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `cat /etc/apt/source.list`?

Comment: @MikeWild updated.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the second part, that should be `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the GNOME Testing PPA you have installed (*ricotz/testing*) wants to provide its own version of *libxkbcommon* which doesn't meet the requirements for rofi. Assuming you're using Loki you should have *libxkbcommon 0.5.0* available from the Ubuntu repos.

If you want a specific package from the *ricotz/testing* PPA without bringing in all of the others then you can use apt pinning as described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/170265). But honestly I would recommend against this as you can end up with a very broken system if you don't know what you're doing.

I would personally recommend the following:

1. Uninstall whatever package you installed from the *ricotz/testing* PPA.
2. Delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-trusty.list` to remove the PPA.
3. Update the apt database with `sudo apt update`.
4. Install rofi with `sudo apt install rofi`.